# R leaflet package inline in IPython Notebook

Tags: r, ipython, leaflet, knitr

I'm using R in Ipython Notebook with R line and cell magics. All of my R plots print automatically inline except for the R package leaflet which opens in a new browser tab.

I've tried using %capture to capture the output. I've also tried doing different versions of --inline.

In knitr, the map is included inside the file following the code chunk. Any idea on how to get this functionality in ipython notebook using R?

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Edit:
%%capture only works with strings.

Comment: I guess the short answer is Python is not R, and the ipython magic does not really understand the magic in leaflet/htmlwidgets, which is not only about stdout, but also injecting JS libraries into the HTML header.

Answer (score 1):

You can display interactive maps inline using `rMaps`.

There is a demonstration notebook here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/front-to-back/blob/master/R_demo.ipynb